# Making sense of dirac delta of a function $\delta(\psi) = \int \mathscr{D}\varphi e^{-i\int\bar{\varphi}\psi}$

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, mathematical-physics

I am currently trying to learn about the MSR Formalism, which rephrases SDE problems in terms of path integrals. This is in the context of turbulence for plasma physics; I know that path integrals do not really have a rigorous mathematical interpretation yet, aside from the Feynman-Kac formula, but I was wondering if there is a way to make rigorous sense of the following representation of the Dirac $\delta$-function of a function in a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.01427) of Canet and [this website](https://inordinatum.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/a-quick-introduction-to-the-martin-siggia-rose-formalism/):

$$\delta(\psi) \sim \int\mathscr{D}\varphi\ e^{-i\int_t\bar{\varphi}\psi}.\tag{1}$$

Here, $\psi$ is some scalar field of spacetime, and $\mathscr{D}$ is supposed to be a sort of "measure" on the space of these fields. The field $\varphi$ is called an *auxiliary* or *response field*. I recognize this is formally like the definition of the Dirac $\delta$ via its inverse Fourier transform, but I am having some difficulty parsing this. Any ideas on how to make sense of this equation would be greatly appreciated!

**—Edit—**

After some further research, I think what I need is the calculus of white noise processes!

Comment: As you said, it is a functional analog of the delta function, through a "functional Fourier transform", such that variables are replaced by functions and the integral by a functional integral; $\phi$ is the original function and $\psi$ plays the role of the conjugated variable in a functional Fourier space. I'm not sure there's something more deep to understand there.

Comment: @Abezhiko do you have any references for a "functional Fourier transform"?

Comment: Not really, sorry :/ However, in a way, all the stuff with the partition functional $Z[J]$ and the source field $J$ (which takes the role of the conjugate Fourier variable) simulate a functional Fourier transform.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Abezhiko. I'll use it as a black box for a bit, and I can come back to better understand later!

Comment: This is just a functional version of $\delta (x)\sim\int dp e^{ipx}$ in the usual calculas.  You can find representation of the Dirac delta function in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function.

Comment: Which eq.? Which page? What is the difference between $\bar{\varphi}$ and $\varphi$? Are the variables real or complex?

Comment: @Qmechanic this is on page 8 of the paper, under equation 3.6. $\varphi$ is a complex scalar field and $\bar{\varphi}$ is its conjugate.

Comment: The equation below eq. (3.6) does not make sense/contains typos.

Comment: Also please doublecheck eq. (1).

Comment: @Qmechanic As far as I can tell, the equation below (3.6) should be of the form if eq (1) here. Regardless I do think I know where/what to look at now. Thanks!

Comment: Why is $\varphi$ in the integral measure while $\bar{\varphi}$ is in the integrand of eq. (1)?? If $\bar{\varphi}$ is a complex-valued integration variable, then eq. (1) is mathematically ill-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some references which seem appropriate from my pedestrian perspective.

---

The formula

[image]

from Hida et al.'s *White Noise: An Infinite Dimensional Calculus*, p.322 seems to match fairly well with the formula in question.

Here

- $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ is the complex valued tempered distributions on $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. the dual space of the space of complex valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ all of whose derivatives exist and decay faster than any polynomial) endowed with the cylinder $\sigma$-algebra (= optimal $\sigma$-algebra that makes finitely many simultaneous evaluations measurable),
- $\mu$ is a certain fully supported probability measure like a "Gaussian" on $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$,
- $:\bullet:_y$ is an operator like a "renormalization" w/r/t $y\in\mathbb{S}'(\mathbb{R})$,
- $\widetilde{\delta}_0$ is the delta white noise functional at $0\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$.

See also Kubo & Yokoi's "A Remark on the Space of Testing Random Variables in the White Noise Calculus" for the definition of the delta white noise functional, as well as Hida's "Analysis of Brownian Functionals" (it seems there are at least three distinct publications by Hida with this title; one of them is available at https://hdl.handle.net/11299/4378)

---

In the section before the section that includes the above formula (along with a formula for Fourier transform), some heuristics are provided: Let $(\Omega,\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space (to be suppressed), $y:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^k$ be a Gaussian random variable with mean $0$ and covariance operator $\text{Id}$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_operator). Then for fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}^k$, the expectation $\mathbb{E}_y(\exp(-i\, x\bullet y))$ of the random variable $\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$, $\omega\mapsto \exp(-i\, x\bullet y(\omega))$ ($\bullet$ is the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^k$) w/r/t $y$ is $\exp(-|x|^2/2)$. Then the renormalization of $y\mapsto \exp(-i\, x\bullet y)$ w/r/t $y$ is defined by

$$:\exp(-i\, x\bullet y):_y = \dfrac{\exp(-i\, x\bullet y)}{\mathbb{E}_y(\exp(-i\, x\bullet y))} = \exp(-i\, x\bullet y+|x|^2/2).$$

Then for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^k,\text{leb}_{\mathbb{R}^k};\mathbb{C})$ the Fourier transform is:

\begin{align*}
\widehat{f}:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{C},\,\, 
y\mapsto &\dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^{k/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} f(x)\,\exp(-i\, x\bullet y)\, d\text{leb}_{\mathbb{R}^k}(x) \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} f(x)\, :\exp(-i\, x\bullet y):_y\, d\text{gau}_{\mathbb{R}^k}(x),
\end{align*}

where $\text{leb}_{\mathbb{R}^k}$ and $\text{gau}_{\mathbb{R}^k}$ are the Lebesgue measure and the standard Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}^k$, respectively. In the infinite-dimensional setting the formula above is based on this (although the renormalization is more involved, and the formula for Fourier transform is still more subtle).

Comment: Thank you @Alp Uzman, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @ZachHunsucker I'm glad it was helpful. You had already done most of the work by making the connection with white noise calculus.